# Make canvas area into an object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there a way, without external libraries, to make a specific area of a canvas into an independent object. For example on a canvas you take a 50 by 40 rectangle and make it have events independent from the whole canvas.

Comment: I wonder how libraries do it then...

Comment: which library does it?

Comment: I know kinetic allows you to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the canvas is just pixels and the shapes drawn on the canvas are not "remembered".

What you need to do is listen for events on the canvas and then test if the mouse event occurred over the rectangle you're interested in by comparing the mouse coordinates with the X/Y, Width/Height of that rectangle.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. Though I ran into another issue... which means I have a bit more work to do! :3 But that makes me wonder about Kinetic though.

Comment: KineticJS is a great little canvas library (along with other canvas libs like FabricJS, CreativeJS, PaperJS)

Comment: I realize that. What I was saying is I don't know HOW they do that. I have an idea, but it seems complicated which might why it is a slow library.

Comment: Agreed, very complicated.  Since canvas is very fast (redraw 60fps) they can afford to be complicated.  Still, if you add a large quantity of objects they do start to slow down.

Comment: Well there was two moderately sized objects and it was incredibly slow. Maybe it is just my computer though. While this is unrelated (sort of) would you recommend a library and if so which one?

Comment: Recommendation depends on your project. Kinetic has a nice tutorial site for ease of learning. Fabric has excellent integration with SVG. Paper has some amazing mathematic algorithms. BTW, if your project was incredibly slow with only 2 objects...something is wrong :-/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45037/discussion-between-auragar-and-marke)